# Bash prompt error when pressing up arrow

Tags: macos, bash

I've written this nice and colorful prompt for my OS X terminal:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ [\1]/'
}

export PS1="\e]2;\w\a\e[1;30;1m\][\u@\[\033[0;36m\]\h\e[1;30;1m\]:\[\033[0;35m\]\w\e[1;30;1m\]] \[\033[0;31m\](\t) \[\033[0;33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\n\[\033[0m\]\e[1;30;1m\]\$\[\e[0m\]"
```

I `source ~/.bash_profile` it and it works fine. except when I use the arrow up to navigate the history I get a weird thing happening.

basically the beginning of the `source ~/.bash_profile` command in the history, becomes part of the prompt. when I `ctrl+c` or `enter` it returns to normal, but as soon as I see the history of the `source` command the prompt changes again.

Here's an example where I've seen the history and then `ctrl+u` and typed `ls`:

```
[user@host:~/Documents] (14:01:40)  [branch]
$source ~/.ls
```

Any clue about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've completely banjanxed bash's idea of what's been printed and what it has to erase/rewrite as it displays command history and lets you edit the command line.  This is because you've made a real hash of that prompt.

- Use either `\e` or `\033` consistently, for your own sanity.
- Make your `\[` and `\]` strictly matching non-nesting pairs.
- Make sure that *all* non-printing sequences are within `\[` and `\]` (and that, conversely, that all printing sequences are not).

(This is why I personally prefer the Z Shell and its alternative prompt expansion mechanism for when I want wacky coloured prompts.  It *knows* that things like `%F{green}` aren't printing sequences, without having to be told; and it also works out the correct escape sequences from `terminfo`, without having them hardwired.)

Comment: thanks, good idea I turned to use zsh which I didn't know before and looks real cool.