# A tab in Tmux results in an indent and tabcompletion

Tags: tmux, tab-completion

I ruined my tabcompletion in Tmux. When I use tabcompletion and I've multiple options which fit the prefix Tmux is acting weird.

Assume I've a folder with subfolders `downloads` and `documents`. When I run `cd ~/do<TAB>` my Tmux show this:

[image]

```
# print $TERM
screen
```

I use Tmux in combination with ZSH. Here's a [link](https://github.com/OrangeTux/dotfiles/tree/master/home) to my dotfiles.

Answer (score 1):

I had a syntax error in my my zsh-theme which caused this behaviour.

I [fixed](https://github.com/OrangeTux/dotfiles/commit/379fd2b41d4d3e3a17b54293dcf9ec96e83c40f6) the syntax errors:

```
- $fg[cyan]%*$reset_color
+ %{$fg[cyan]%}%*%{$reset_color%}
```

Comment: [You're still doing it the hard way](http://superuser.com/a/695350/38062), given [the visual effects available](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects).

Comment: @JdeBP [I simplified ZSH visualisation](https://github.com/OrangeTux/dotfiles/commit/2cf837911a5092b339db3603f9f9ff107687b409). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar problem floating around, regarding remnant characters after `TAB` completion (like `ls /e` -> `TAB` -> `ls /e/etc`). The solution in those cases is usually setting the right UTF-8 locale (e.g. `echo “export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8” >> .zshrc`). What are your settings regarding locale/encoding?

Comment: How can I check my current locale?

Comment: Just run `locale` in your shell.

Comment: everything is en_US.UTF-8, except LC_ALL, that is blanc.

Comment: I presume your tab completion works fine outside of Tmux?

Comment: No, it didn't work outside Tmux either.