# Tmux causeing issues with Bash up-arrow

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

When using `tmux`, I have issues of **ghost characters when using the Up and Down arrow keys** in Bash. If I press <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> a few times and then press <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> a few times, then **the first few characters of a previous command remain on the Bash line**.

For instance, take this clean Bash line:

```
$
```

Now I press <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> three times:

```
$ ls /home/dotancohen/Downloads
```

Now I press <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> three times:

```
$ ls /home/do
```

**I can reproduce the issue with no ~/.tmux.conf file, after exiting and restarting `tmux`.** How should I diagnose this?

**Edit:** Here is my `$PS1`:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\] - \h():\W$ \[\]
```

Note that everything from the second backslash up until the last close bracket is green. This function creates the prompt:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(
    cat<<-'EOF'

    retval=$?

    RED=$(tput setaf 1)
    GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
    STOP=$(tput sgr0)

    c=0
    for i in $retval ${PIPESTATUS[@]}; do ((c += $i)); done

    if (($c == 0)); then
        PS1="\[$GREEN\] - \h(${WINDOW}):\W$ \[$STOP\]"
    else
        PS1="\[$RED\] - \h(${WINDOW}):\W$ \[$STOP\]"
    fi
EOF
)
```

Comment: Put the result of `echo $PS1` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is, of course, the same problem and the same cause as at https://superuser.com/a/695350/38062 .  In this particular case, the non-spacing escape sequence that you've forgotten to delimit with `\[` and `\]`, and that is banjanxing bash, is apparently somewhere in the expansion of `${WINDOW}`.