# This prompt makes terminals wrap mid screen why?

Tags: bash, terminal, terminal.app, .bash-profile

I've the following PS1 prompt:

```
export PS1="\e[1m\e[38;5;198m\u\e[0m @ \e[1m\e[38;5;208m\h\e[0m : \e[1m\w\e[0m\e[38;5;226m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[0m \e[1m>>>\e[0m "
```

what happens is that when typing and it reaches halfway through the terminal, it will send the cursor at the beginning of the line and overwrite itself like:

```
rossid @ HOST : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents >>>

oussid @ HOST : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents >>>  this is just a test to show what happens nothing seri
```

(the rest of the string serious replaces the beginning)

Any idea why? (I'm using osx standard terminal and IntelliJ terminal... all do the same)

Comment: This is a very common FAQ. Search before asking.

Comment: Inded. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/ , https://superuser.com/questions/695338/ , and many others.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose all the non printable escape sequences between `\[` and `\]`. For example:

```
  PS1="\[\e[1m\]\[\e[38;5;198m\]\u\[\e[0m\] @ "
```

[Shows only part of your prompt. Do the same for rest.]